# What happens if a Divination wizard uses the Portent feature to replace an enemy's initiative roll, when the DM rolls once for a group of enemies?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, wizard, initiative

Say 4 goblins ambush a level 2 party, everyone is surprised but the Wizard decides to use his Portent feature to influence the initiative roll of the enemy. One of his portents is a natural 1, and he uses that die to replace the initiative roll.

**Do all 4 of the goblins' initiative change to 1 or does just one goblin change?**

Here's what I got from a reading of the PHB:

> PHB 189
>
> ### Initiative
>
> ... When combat starts, every participant makes a Dexterity Check to determine their place in the initiative order. **The DM makes one roll for an entire group of identical creatures**, so each member of the group acts at the same time...

Emphasis mine. Reading the bolded text, it seems that in cases of identical creatures, Portent *can* effectively cripple the entire initiative of the opposing team.

However, when you read the first sentence, it seems that the entire group shouldn't be crippled by a single portent roll as each creature should be rolling separately and the bolded text really just says, *"hey, don't waste your time on rolling for each goblin. Just roll once and they all go together."*

A big factor of my hesitance to rule on the side of the first interpretation, is that it seems too overpowered for a 2nd-level feature.

So which is which? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

## No, this will not work.

The description of the Divination wizard's Portent feature (PHB, p. 116) says:

> You can replace any attack roll, saving throw, or ability check made by you or
> **a** creature that you can see with one of these foretelling rolls.

An initiative check is an ability check so it is an eligible target for Portent. However, it only affects "**a** creature"; even though the DM rolls once for a group of creatures, this is a roll for **each** of the creatures individually, and the player can only substitute the Portent roll for **one** of the creatures. This effectively breaks the creatures into two groups of identical creatures - the one affected by the Portent and the rest who aren't.

Comment: missed a single letter... and my whole life is a lie... Thanks!

Comment: Could you rather read it that the portent replaces a roll made by a creature, the initiative roll is not made by a creature (it's made by a group of creatures), therefore you cannot replace that initiative roll at all? Choose something else.

Comment: @SteveJessop Well, at my tables, creatures don't make *any* rolls, only players make rolls. Then again, players are "creatures", I suppose... But no, that's not a very interesting reading... ;)

Comment: One could also argue that at the time initiative is rolled you likely couldn't see the target to assign the 1 in the first place, otherwise it wouldn't be much of an ambush.

Comment: This answer makes sense because a creature affected by a spell (could be a spell that gives a +1 to initiative) would then be in a different group of creatures since it is not *somewhat different* from the others.

Answer (score -3):

If surprised, you can't use portent - you can't see them.  If not surprised, you probably can since you see each other, close and engage (which sets up initiative, a composite of mostly random factors, so luck might favor you).  I wouldn't worry too much saddling a whole group pf monsters with a 1.  They get their turn, eventually, and Diviners don't always roll great or rotten numbers - they most often have mid range numbers on both d20's.  Portent can help, but there's probably something more vital to use it on than initiative, anyway.  I wouldn't worry too much about this being an unbalancing factor.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour] for an intro to how we do things around here.  This answer could be improved by adding rules citations and/or play experience to back it up - how do you know that this isn't worth worrying about as a balancing factor?

Comment: Surprise =/= hidden, you can see a creature but still be surprised. Perhaps you mean hidden?

Comment: @daze413 actually surprise means precisely that; RAW a creature is only surprised if all of its opponents were hidden from it at the start of combat.

Comment: A roll is a random determination.  Once replaced with the portent ability, it is no longer a roll or random. One can't replace non random events not described, like a portent.  True, portents are randomly determined by rolls, but are not rolls anymore.  The surprise rule doesn't blind, but since you have to see the intended target, I don't think a diviner could use portent while surprised.  In fact, if surprise one is precluded from taking an action or making even a reaction (which is almost meta game fast at times, like with the shield spell).  1 DM might rule it's OK, but I wouldn't. IMO.