# Do creatures of the same type go on the same turn?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, initiative

According to the [Basic Rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#Initiative):

> Initiative determines the order of turns during combat. When combat
>   starts, every participant makes a Dexterity check to determine their
>   place in the initiative order. The DM makes one roll for an entire
>   group of identical creatures, so each member of the group acts at the
>   same time.

Does that mean that the creatures of the same type share a turn, or only have the same initiative? If they go on the same turn, it gives a significant advantage to enemies with pack tactics, and makes "wakeup chains" against sleep/hypnotic pattern stronger.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How do I handle initiative and turns for a group of monsters?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/138850/33569) Also related: [How can I solve burst damage problem when rolling group initiative?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/124789/33569), [If the DM rolls initiative once for a group of monsters, how do end-of-turn effects work?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/143265/33569), [What happens if a Divination wizard uses the Portent feature to replace an enemy's initiative roll, when the DM rolls once for a group of enemies?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/87575/33569)

Comment: Does the [first linked question above](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/138850/33569) match your own question? If not, please edit your question to clarify how it is different.

Comment: Does this answer your question: "[How do creatures moving on the same initiative handle the effects of Sleep and Hypnotic Pattern?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/119029)"

Comment: @Medix2 Yes, that answers my question. Thank you!